# Customizing tickmark and ticklabel positions in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to have exactly one tickmark per datapoint.

I would *love* to give an array with the datapoints as parameter to the refreshTicksHorizontal in the NumberAxis (actually i work with symbolAxis which is a subclass) class which i have overwritten. Actually I did this, but I have absolutely know idea (after some hours of getting just nearly correct results) how to convert this double values into the pixel (or at least somehow mysteriously related to tickUnit) values i have to put into the currentTickValue variable in refreshTicksHorizontal.

I also tried - since the datapoints all have the same distance to its neighbours - to give

`ratio = (datapoint[1] - datapoint[0]) / (Axis.UpperBound - datapoint[0])`

as parameter and different other things. But i dont know the (pixel respectively Java2D)-value of the first datapoint so i could have my i-th currentTickValue as

`ratio*i * (dataArea.getMaxX() - firstDataPointInJava2D)`...

In my (wrong) solutions i always get slightly too big or too less tick mark distances. Do you know how to fix this or are there possibly entirely different approaches to the problem?

**EDIT**

To illustrate the problem here is a compiling minimalistic example:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] dataPoints = {1.249860779781E12, 1.249861186272E12, 1.249861592763E12, 1.249861999254E12,
                1.249862405745E12};
        String[] dataNames = {"Hades", "Hagen", "Herakles", "Hermes", "Horowitz"};
        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(-2, -2, 4, 4);
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true);

        XYSeries[] lines = new XYSeries[5];
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            lines[i] = new XYSeries(new Integer(i).toString());
            lines[i].add(dataPoints[i], 0.05d);
            lines[i].add(dataPoints[i], 0.95d);
            dataset.addSeries(lines[i]);
            renderer.setSeriesShape(i, shape);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(i, Color.black);
        }

        ValueAxis timeAxis = new DateAxis("");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("");
        yAxis.setVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        yAxis.setRange(0.0d, 1.0d);

        SymbolAxis labelAxis = new SymbolAxis("", dataNames);
        labelAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);

        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, timeAxis, yAxis, renderer);

        plot.setDomainAxis(1, labelAxis);
        plot.setDomainAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", plot);
        chart.removeLegend();
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(panel);
        frame.add(scroller);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The result looks like this: 
[image: Example Plot]

So far so good. The PROBLEM is, i want the names (Horowitz and so on) exactly over the lines. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Ok. I added a code example. Hopefully this helps enlightening what i want to do.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a purely empirical measure, they line up perfectly using either

```
timeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.125);
timeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.125);
```

or

```
timeAxis.setRange(dataPoints[0] - 200000, dataPoints[4] + 200000);
```

You may be able to generalize this as a function of your dataset.

Comment: Excellent! DYM `timeAxis.setRange(labelAxis.getRange)`?

Comment: Basically the other way round. I've read the upper and lower bounds from the time axis and set them (after some scaling) as bounds for the labelAxis. Mmh but wait, actually both should work (i.e. labels exactly where the lines end) ...